# How do I update the same object format when I make a new API call in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

```
if (lat !== 0 && lon !== 0) {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios(
      ` https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${apiKey}&q=${lat},${lon}`
    );

    setLoading(false);
    const results = response.data;
    setWeatherData({
      name: results.location.name,
      country: results.location.country,
      region: results.location.region,
      temperature: results.current.temp_c,
      description: results.current.condition.text,
      icon: results.current.condition.icon,
      humidity: results.current.humidity,
    });
```

This is the data that is set when the website is rendered, it gets the current location of a user and gathers the data. Then I have an input box where a user can search for a city and it displays the data.

```
const handleSearch = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
setLoading(true);
if (search === '') return;
const response = await axios.get(
  ` https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${apiKey}&q=${search}`
);
const results = response.data;
setWeatherData({
  name: results.location.name,
  country: results.location.country,
  region: results.location.region,
  temperature: results.current.temp_c,
  description: results.current.condition.text,
  icon: results.current.condition.icon,
  humidity: results.current.humidity,
});
```

I do not know how to use the same format again, so I copied the same object, which works just fine. How do I set the data rather than copying it? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await axios.get(
    ` https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${apiKey}&q=${search === '' ? lat + ',' + lon : search }`
  );
```

You should try this.